# git backout master, push to branch, to go into master at later date

Tags: git

How would I go about:

1) Reverting changes pushed out to master (remote)
2) Moving those changes to a separate branch
3) Move those changes back into master at a later time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First do 2), but only if you really need the branch.

```
git branch changes
```

Then do 1) using [`git revert`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html).

Finally, redo the changes by reverting the revert commits.

Comment: Will this still work when there are changes applied to master after the initial revert?

Comment: @Corey Hart: it will, with the usual caveats for merges and reverts: you may have to do hand-editing if the files affected have changed in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already cloned the remote repo and you're on the `master` branch, you could do the following:

Do the second thing first:

`git branch new-branch`

Then revert changes on master:

1. `git revert <commit-id-you-want-reverted>` (repeat for each bad commit)
2. `git push origin HEAD:master`

Later, cherry-pick them back:

`git cherry-pick <commits-from-new-branch>; git push origin HEAD:master`

I *think* that'll work, but I haven't tried it myself. YMMV. I think simply pulling the changes back (without cherry-picking) won't work because they'll have the original commit IDs and git might know that it doesn't need to pull them in...then again, maybe with a new HEAD it *will* work. Try it and see :)